# x-magento-init: "variable is not defined"

Tags: magento2

I am completely lost trying to get my `text/x-magento-init` working.

I have included this in my template file and I can see it in the page source:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
                "a": "<?php echo 'Hello from template' ?>"
             }
    }
 </script>
```

I want to call this variable `a` in my JS function, but when I do that, I get an error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`

Do I need to call the `a` in a special way or is there a mistake in my `x-magento-init`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
                "ComponentName": {
                    "a": "<?php echo 'Hello from template' ?>"
                 }
             }
    }
</script>
```

Here component name will replace full name or requirejs-config.js mapping name. Like

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
                "VendorName_ModuleName/js/custom": {
                    "a": "<?php echo 'Hello from template' ?>"
                 }
             }
    }
</script>
```

[Click here for detail](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html)